# SQL como agregar registros a una tabla combinando registros de otras dos

Tags: sql, insertar

Mejor con un ejemplo.

Partiendo de una tabla de `clientes` y otra de `ArticulosOfertados`, quiero añadir en una tercera tabla, por cada `cliente`, los registros en la tabla `ArticulosOfertados`.

Estoy intentándolo con `while`, pero no se la forma de avanzar al siguiente cliente para continuar añadiendo los artículos:

TABLA_CLIENTE, 2 registros: Cliente1, Cliente2
TABLA_ARTICULOS_OFERTADOS, dos registros: Articulo1, Articulo2

Quiero añadir a la `TABLA_ARTICULOS_OFERTADOS`, la combinación de ambos para que quede algo así:

`TABLA_ARTICULOS_OFERTADOS` (4 registros, dos campos): Cliente1   Articulo1, Cliente1   Articulo2, Cliente2   Articulo1, Cliente2   Articulo2

Gracias,

Comment: Parece que lo que en verdad necesitas es una Vista no una tabla

Comment: No se que tiene que ver while, pero estas mostrando un producto cartesiano....

Comment: Hola, he simplificado la pregunta porque la duda principal es como ir recorriendo registros. En la tabla clientes hay más campos y uno de ellos es oferta (s/n) y en la de artículos está el mismo campo oferta (s/n). Necesito tener otra tercera tabla que contenga por cada cliente marcado con oferta (s/n) todos los artículos que están marcados también a true en su oferta (s/n).